# How to give commands in a CMD window using AutoIt (*.au3) scripts?

Tags: cmd, autoit

What I have tried and didn't work:

1. I opened `cmd.exe`
2. Typed "cd\"  >> without quotes
3. Pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Typed "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins"
5. Pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>
6. Typed "jenkins.exe start"
7. Pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I have also used the `sleep` command after every type, just to make sure that it is not skipping because of fast execution.

```
;Run application
Run("cmd.exe")

;Wait for CMD to be opened
WinWaitActive("Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", "", 15)

;Write some commands on cmd
ControlSend("Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", "", "Edit1", "cd\")
Sleep(10000)
Send("{Enter}")
Sleep(10000)
ControlSend("Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", "", "Edit1", "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins")
Sleep(10000)
Send("{Enter}")
ControlSend("Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", "", "Edit1", "jenkins.exe start")
Sleep(10000)
Send("{Enter}")
```

---

I got the answer:

```
ControlSend("Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", "", "", "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins")
```

I needed to remove "Edit" , as cmd is not an editable window.

Answer (score 7):

Start your program directly:

```
RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c jenkins.exe start", "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use &

Exp :

```
$CMD = 'cd %tmp% & md 1 & md 2 & cd %tmp%/1 & md 3 4 & md "5 6" &'
RunWait(@ComSpec & " /c " & $CMD )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Run("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
WinWaitActive("C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe")
send('cd C:\Program Files (x86)\' & "{ENTER}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;Run application
Run("cmd.exe")

;Wait for CMD to be opened
WinWaitActive("Administrator: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe", "", 1)
Send('C:' & "{ENTER}")
Send('cd Program Files (x86)' & "{ENTER}")
Send('cd TestAPP' & "{ENTER}")
Send('start testApp.exe' & "{ENTER}")
```